# topshelf uninstall command not deleting the EF database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, topshelf

I have a basic console application service which have 2 methods `Start` and `Stop` and running this as window service using `Topshelf`.

```
 public class MyService
{
    public void Start()
    {
        using (var db = new PersonDbContext())
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                LastName = "test",
            };

            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        //var context = new PersonDbContext();
        //context.Database.Delete();
    }
}
```

Here `Start` method create the database and insert person record, here I am using EF Code First. This means when I am installing service using `Topshelf` and starting the service, database is created.

```
 HostFactory.Run(configure =>
        {
            configure.Service<MyService>(service =>
            {
                service.ConstructUsing(s => new MyService());
                service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
                service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
            });
            //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
            configure.RunAsVirtualServiceAccount();
            configure.SetServiceName("MyWindowServiceWithTopshelf");
            configure.SetDisplayName("MyWindowServiceWithTopshelf");
            configure.SetDescription("My .Net windows service with Topshelf");

            configure.BeforeUninstall(() => { DeleteDatabase(); });
        });


 private static void DeleteDatabase()
    {
        var context = new PersonDbContext();
        context.Database.Delete();
    }
```

The database is successfully DELETED when I am adding delete database code on `Stop` method, means when service is stopped.

But I want to delete the database on service uninstallation process.  I am trying to add delete database code at `configure.BeforeUninstall(() => { DeleteDatabase(); });` or `configure.AfterUninstall(() => { DeleteDatabase(); });`, but database is NOT deleted?

On service stop, same code is working fine and database delete is OK. Please suggest.

Comment: The u installation is through Local administrator user hence look like database is not found and deleted.  The database is created by nt account

Comment: Is there a way to hookup STOP method when only uninstall case